# Is there a simple Mercurial repo downloader

Tags: mercurial

I use TurtoiseHg on my main machine and it works great, however I sometimes want to quickly download a repo on other machines (Windows) on which no clients are installed.

For Git and SVN I have found this little program [Download SVN (and GIT)](http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/) that works great, I am struggling to find anything similar for Mercurial though. Any ideas?

Comment: This program seems to download the most recent revision, not the whole repository. You can set up `hg serve` to include _download zip_ links for every revision, no software altogether required on the client side. Does this work for you?

Comment: @Helgi I dont control the servers unfortunately.

Comment: One possibility is to clone it on a machine that has hg installed, then zip it and distribute as needed.

Comment: @PeterRowell These downloads are more a spur of the moment type of deal I dont pre plan them.

Comment: you could perhaps use: wget -r -np <your repo url>

Answer (score 0):

You can just click the zip file link if that's enabled on the given hgweb installation (default is not to, IIRC). Other than that, not really, since there's not an hg wireprotocol command for walking file content like this.